# Center n amount of v-col in vuetify grid with added spacing

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to center `n` amount of v-cols with spacing left and right of the cols but unable to center the `v-cols` aligned with the above `v-cols`. Note that the responsiveness is working as intended, but at max screen size I want to limit it to two `v-cols` and align it to the other `v-row` horizontal lengths, all while keeping the same lengths of the v-cols.

Currently I get this:
[image]

From

```
<v-container>
  <v-row dense justify="center">
    <v-col cols="12" md="6" lg="4" xl="3">
      // ...
    </v-col>
  </v-row>

  <v-row dense justify="center">
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" xs="6" md="6" lg="4" xl="3">
      // ...
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" xs="6" md="6" lg="4" xl="3">
      // ...
    </v-col>
  </v-row>

  <v-row dense justify="center">
    <v-col v-for="(item, n) in list" :key="n" cols="12" sm="6" md="6" lg="4" xl="4">
      // ...
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
```

What I am trying to accomplish can be seen below;
[image]

What can be done to add spacing to the sides of the red `v-cols` to keep them aligned with the other above v-cols (in above v-rows)?

Edit:
Works now with this code:

```
<v-container>
<!-- .. other rows -->

<v-row justify="center">
  <v-col cols="24" sm="12" xs="12" md="12" lg="8" xl="6">
    <v-row dense justify="center" class="green">
      <v-col v-for="(item, n) in list" :key="n" sm="12" xs="12" md="12" lg="8" xl="6" class="br text-center red">
        // content
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
</v-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your layout in something like this:

```
<v-row justify="center" align="center">
    <v-col cols="10">
      // Your layout goes here
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

First row element makes the col inside it to be centered and since the cols prop of the col element is set to 10 (or other number other than 12 which fits your needs), it has an equal space from the sides.

So this way any layout you put inside this wrapper would be aligned.

Edit: I worked with this idea and prepared a pen for you to look at. here is the pen:

[vuetify layout code pen](https://codepen.io/Hamid-Niakan/pen/ExgajYV?editors=1000)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer - I might have forgotten to mention, but I want to limit the number of dynamic v-cols to 2 per row. And the dynamic v-cols are the same width as the above v-cols (view image above). That's where I am unable to center and align it with the above v-cols

Comment: Like, when there are only 2 v-cols they are perfectly aligned. But, when there are 3 or more, it will display 3 v-cols in a single row and it wont be aligned to the above v-row.

Comment: @asisleep updated the code pen example (if I'm not mistaken about what you mean), but basically you can limit the v-cols to 2 per row by setting its col prop to 6

Comment: But I solved it by adding the v-cols in a row>col>row structure! :) Thanks